# Concept and ranges

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

I'd like to define a concepts that is true if

1. t.ok(c) compiles and returns a bool, where t is a template parameter of type T and c is a "concrete" type of type C
2. t.around(c) compiles and returns something that can be iterated over (the type of each element is C)

So far, I wrote the following mwe, but can't get my head around it to make it work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
#include <ranges>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Integ
{
    int val;  
};

template<class Cont, class T>
concept range_of = std::ranges::range<Cont> 
        && std::is_same_v<T, std::ranges::range_value_t<Cont>>;

template<class T, class Cont>
concept LookingRight = requires(const T& t, const Integ& i)
{
    { t.ok(i) } -> std::same_as<bool>; //ok if t.ok(i) compiles and returns bool
    { t.around(i) } -> range_of<Cont,Integ>; //ok it t.around(i) compiles and returns sth iterable
};


std::vector<Integ> filter(const auto& LookingRight lr, const Integ& i)
{ //probably a better way to filter with ranges
    std::vector<Integ> v;
    for(const Integ& ii : lr.around(i))
        if(lr.ok(ii))
            v.push_back(ii);
    return v;
}

struct Even
{
    bool ok(const Integ& i) const 
    { 
        return i.val % 2 == 0; 
    }   
    
    std::array<Integ,4> around(const Integ& i) const
    {
        return {Integ(i.val-2), Integ(i.val-1), Integ(i.val+1), Integ(i.val+2)};
    }
};

int main()
{
    Even e;
    for(auto i : filter(e, {0}))
        cout << i.val << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

I have some questions :

- how to make it work, and what did I do wrong ?
- why do I have to write `-> std::same_as<bool>` and I can't just write `-> bool`

I'm compiling with g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0. as `g++ -std=c++20 -o mwe mwe.cpp`

The compiler tells me that `range_of<Cont, Integ> doesn't name a type` (in the declaration of LookingRight). I also have syntax errors in the prototype of filter (I suspect they are there because LookingRight isn't properly defined)

Comment: "*how to make it work*" - You did not specify how it "does not work". You lack a useful problem description here.

Comment: Regarding your second question, what should `-> bool` mean? Is it exactly `bool` or something convertible to `bool` like an `int`? Neither is inherently better than the other and both are useful, so if one is fixed in plain `-> bool`, you lose the ability to describe the other. That's why the syntax requires a concept to describe what we mean  exactly, `std::same_as<bool>` or `std::converitble_to<bool>`.

Comment: Obviously, `filter()` needs to accept two arguments, how does `filter(e.around({0}))` work?

Comment: Ok, I understand for `-> bool` now :)

Comment: and you're right, filter needs 2 args (I edited the original post)

Comment: (still doesn't work)

Answer (score 2):

> t.around(c) compiles and returns something that can be iterated over (the type of each element is C)

This is essentially two requirements. The result must be a range and the value type for that range must match a given type. `std::ranges::range` only answers the question "is it a range", not what it is a range over.

So you're going to need a concept that combines both questions:

```
template<typename R, typename T>
concept range_over =
  std::ranges::range<R> &&
  std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, T>;
```

You may need to apply `remove_cv_t` to `T`.

Comment: Not the latter, `value_type` is never cv-qualified.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I refactored my concepts to ```template<class Cont, class T>
concept range_of = std::ranges::range<Cont> && std::is_same_v<T, std::ranges::range_value_t<Cont>>;``` and `LookingRight` to `template<class T, class Cont> concept LookingRight ... { t.around(i) } -> range_of<Cont,Integ>; `, but so far, gcc tells me that `range_of<Cont, Integ>` doesn't name a type (in the declaration of LookingRight). I also have syntax errors in the prototype of `filter` (I suspect they are there because LookingRight isn't properly defined)

Comment: ... and I edited the original post so include the modifications mentioned above

Comment: (still doesn't work)